# VC++ 2013 debug and release versions

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm just diving into VC++ after a number of years in other areas of programming.  I am puzzled by the errors that come up when I go from a debug version to a release version.  I'm probably doing something stupid here...

For example, this code works fine for debug compiles:

```
ofn.lpstrFile = (LPSTR)title;
```

However, if I go to release mode, I get an error and have to put in a W:

```
ofn.lpstrFile = (LPWSTR)title;
```

What am I doing wrong?  This is not a MFC program, it's really just a very simple program where I read a file, take the information from it to eliminate certain parts of another file, and then write the final file to disc.

Comment: That looks wrong either way. The simple answer is that `UNICODE` is defined in one, but just use wide strings in the first place for interacting with the Windows API and convert anything you need to instead of casting it.

Comment: This is not a unicode project, it's a multi-byte character set project.

Comment: @user792826 In Windows in particular, a multi-byte character set *is* UTF-16 little endian.

Comment: @Qix: That is patently untrue. A MBCS can be anything _but_ Unicode. In particular, all MBCS are supersets of ASCII, and UTF-8 (the only Unicode encoding which is a superset of ASCII) is not a supported MBCS on WIndows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because you have different settings in the Debug and Release configuration. Your debug configuration is set to have the character set "Not set" while the Release configuration is using "Use Unicode character set".

To change the character set go to the project properties, select your configuration and from Configuration Properties > General > Character Set select the same for all your configurations.

Comment: This goes for *all* settings; if you want them to be the same in both configurations, you have to change them in *both configurations*. An easy way is to use the drop-down menu at the top in Visual Studio and select *All Configurations*, and then change whatever options you want to apply to all configurations.

Comment: Ah- that did it- thanks!  I had forgotten that debug and release versions can have different settings.  Will mark this as the correct answer in 3 minutes...